# How to call event after value is changed programmatically in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a form that contains an empty textarea that should be updated programmatically once a function has run. The said function converts an uploaded image to a Base64 string. The textarea is updated to reflect the Base64 string but takes time to do so. I want to trigger an event once it is updated. How do I do this? This is what I tried but it is executed even before the textarea is updated:

```
ta.value = document.getElementById("imgTest").innerHTML;
var event = new Event('change');
ta.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Comment: Trigger the **dispatchEvent(event)** once you uploaded the image. In the above code you are not waiting for the image upload step.

Comment: @SumitherS I have done that. The code above is just after the image is uploaded.

Comment: Trigger the **dispatchEvent(event)** from the image onload event.

`img.onload = () => {
 dispatchEvent(event);
}`

Comment: I'm sorry... I should have added more details. Please check question again @SumitherS